# How to make vim recognize the script type and turn on autoindent and syntax highlighting, without needing to save and reopen file?

Tags: vim

I don't save my shell scripts with a `.sh` extension. So when i launch a new file with vim using `vim <filename>`, it identifies the script type by reading the `shebang`. Naturally, this only happens after I have typed in the shebang, saved and then reopened the file... Was wondering if there is some command line option or vim command mode option so I can avoid these unnecessary steps of saving and reopening, and vim just knows that i am working on a shell script.

Comment: just `:e` the file once after you save it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Without saving the file, you can manually set the filetype to `sh` (shell script).

  ```
  :se ft=sh
  ```
- You can add a mapping to your `.vimrc`. For example, to make <kbd>F3</kbd> apply the command,

  ```
  nnoremap <F3> :set filetype=sh<CR>
  ```
- If you allow for saving the file, do as mentioned by @muru,

  ```
  :w|e
  ```